# Symbolic Link, not accessible from network computer. getting error “The symbolic link cannot be followed because its type is disabled”

Tags: c#

I have created symbolic link for shared folder on my machine and this symbolic link is present in another share folder on same machine. i can access this folder content using symbolic link from the same machine. however when i try to access the symbolic link from another machine. i am getting access denied error on windows xp. and windows 2008 shows access denied error with "The symbolic link cannot be followed because its type is disabled"

i have also used fsutil behavior set SymlinkEvaluation R2R:1 L2R:1 R2L:1 to create symbolic link on my machine( windows 7). i have created symbolic link using kernel32 API CreateSymbolicLink.

i am usign following code to create symbolic link,

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool CreateSymbolicLink(string lpSymlinkFileName, string lpTargetFileName, int dwFlags);
static int SYMLINK_FLAG_DIRECTORY = 1;


string finalTargetD = @"\\abhande-win2k8\CopiedFiles";
string sharedDirectory = @"\\abhande-xp\SharedFiles";


public static void CreateSymLink()
{
 using (WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate())
 {

  if(CreateSymbolicLink(sharedDirectory, finalTargetD, SYMLINK_FLAG_DIRECTORY))
  {
    //symbolic link created successfully
  }
 }

}
```

Do any one have idea why symbolic link is not accessible from another network machine.

Thanks Arvind

Answer (score 3):

The SymlinkEvaluation behaviour needs to be set appropriately on the PC you want to "follow" the symlink on. The symlink source/destination (local/remote) are both relative to the machine opening the symlink.

Comment: MS article on SymlinkEvaluation: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2012/05/07/the-symbolic-link-cannot-be-followed-because-its-type-is-disabled.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It probably is caused by symbolic links being resolved on the client machine instead of the server machine.  You may be looking for a junction point which would be resolved on the server.  Here is another [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492677/c-sharp-createsymboliclink-doesnt-follow-through-share-access/8593556#8593556).