# C# CreateSymbolicLink doesn't follow through share access

Tags: c#, symlink, share

I'm not sure if this is just a C# problem or a windows limitation.

I have a server running my program which makes symbolic links in a shared folder. I can access through this link form the server with a normal disk path and the share path.

If I try to access the same share with an other pc I can't access the linked files. I do can delete rename... the links but I can't follow the links.

I already checked the acl of the link and the target files. Everyone should be able to access.

I use the following function:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool CreateSymbolicLink(string lpSymlinkFileName, string lpTargetFileName, int dwFlags);
```

Maybe I just have to set some additional things? Or do I have to change some windows settings on the server?

Sorry if the solution is not a programming thing but I think here I have the best chances to get help with this.

Edit 1:

I have the share: C:\share

A link: C:\share\file.txt

to the destination: D:\file.txt

If I access the share from a different pc I can't access the data of file.txt.

Comment: What do you specify as the target of your symlinks?

Comment: I specify a local path of the server's pc. I also tried to use network paths but video files can't be played then. I prefer to use local paths and the windows smb/cifs server "translates" them like it is the default behavior with folder junctions.

Answer (score 0):

This page from Tuxera has a good [description of the reason](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/junction-points-and-symbolic-links/)

> The similar concept of symbolic link is also available in Windows
>   Vista. The symbolic links can redirect to a file or a directory
>   defined by an absolute or a relative path. When defined on a remote
>   file system, they are processed on the local system, whereas the
>   directory junctions are processed on the file server, which makes a
>   difference when the target is not accessible by the file server.

The CreateSymbolicLink function will create a link that will be interpreted by the client.  So the client computer (not the server) is trying to access a file with the name d:\file.txt which of course does not exist on the client.

For windows a Junction or [Reparse Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will work on a server like your example.  The easiest way to create one outside of code is to use the SysInternals [Junction tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768).